# Google validation for id_token returns an "invalid_value"

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, google-api, openid, identityserver4

My understanding is that I should be able to issue this sort of request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=<SOME_ID_TOKEN>
```

which should return the decoded information (similar to how it is described in the Google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint).
However, I get  `Bad Request` for a token that I know for a fact is valid.

[image]

The app validating (.NET Core) the token is registered in the Google Dev console, and configured as per this

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
            DisplayName = "Google",
            SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,

            ClientId = "<MY_CLIENT_ID>",
            ClientSecret = "<MY_SECRET>"
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

How do I get the Google token validation (for id tokens) to work? Must be missing something here.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

have you registered your app with Google APIs? If yes, how are you logging into the app and how are you getting this token?

**UPDATE** I'm just configuring client id and client secret and everything else is handled by google middleware.

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
            {
                ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"]
            });
```

and for handling the callbacks after authroization from google I have these functions in my account controller for any external logins. 
ExternalLogin(), ExternalLoginConfirmation(). Check out [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs) sample!

So I'm not handling the id token validation myself by calling the token endpoint but the middleware is handling it. Do you have any particular reason for handling it yourself?

Comment: You could ask these questions as comment. This is not an answer @JayDeeEss

Comment: @MJK I need more than 50 reps to comment and as you can see I don't have 50 yet.

Comment: @JayDeeEss I have updated my question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @JayDeeEss Yeah, I have seen all these IS examples and they do work. However, I need to talk to the Google API directly and according to the Google documentation that should be possible. The reason behind this is that the id token I need to validate comes from a different app. There is an example  [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/securing-net-core-web-api-identityserver4-using-owner-dalvandi-1?trk=mp-author-card) but I cannot get this to work.